# global var on Javascript for Google Map API V2

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I want to create a JavaScript global var that contains some value that I need. I've read some value from an XML file and use it for show a Google Map's map. I would store this information in some variables and show them when users ask for them.

I have this code:

```
var tot_pts = new Array(); //global variable

if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) { 

  // Display the map, with some controls and set the initial location 
  ...

  // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
  function createMarker(point,train) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    return marker;
  }

  request.open("GET", "example.xml", true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      var xmlDoc = GXml.parse(request.responseText);
      //read value on XML
      tot_pts.push(new_path);

      //show all value on map
      for (var i = 0; i < tot_pts.length; i++) {
        point= [];
        point[0]=tot_pts[i].start;
        point[1]=tot_pts[i].end;
        map.addOverlay(new GPolyline(point,tot_pts[i].colour,3));
        marker = createMarker(tot_pts[i].start,tot_pts[i].train);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        marker = createMarker(tot_pts[i].end,tot_pts[i].train);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
      }
    }//end of if request=4
  }// end of on ready...

  request.send(null);

}// end of compatible browser
```

If I shift the last "for loop" to another position in this code the array `tot_pts` is empty. Why does this happen? Can I improve my code in some way?

Comment: It looks like `tot_pts` only gets data stored in it right before that for loop. So when putting the for loop anywhere else, it would make sense for the array to be empty, because nothing has been put it in yet. Even if you know for a fact that the request's readyState is going to be 4, if you put the for loop outside of the `onreadystatechange` function, the request is asynchronous, so the for loop will execute before the `onreadystatechange` function.

Comment: ok, then if I want to wait an user interaction with an HTML interface can I put my listener on a onreadystatechange function? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: It depends what you want to wait to do. If you're waiting for the user interaction before doing the for loop, then I would just put the loop in a separate function, say `putPointsInOverlay`, and then have something like `<button onClick="putPointsInOverlay()">`. If you're waiting for the interaction before GETing the request, then the `onreadystatechange` is fine, and you would want to put `request.open(...);` in a function to be called similarly to the other example.

Answer (score 0):

request.readyState == 4 means the response of XMLHttpRequest is ready. So when you get the response you have your array tot_pts pushed with some value (new_path) at step -> tot_pts.push(new_path);
Until then the array will display empty because it is not explicitly set with values.